# Clear fix HTML is not working in chrome?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I've created [**this simple html**](http://jsbin.com/ukaxav/2/edit) :

there are 2 SPANs here.

one should be beneath the other by clearing the float.

[image]

The `bbb` element has `float:left`

And I used (on the `aaa` element )  , Facebook's "clearfix" CSS which is :

```
 .clearfix:before { content: ""; display: table; }
 .clearfix:after {  content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;}

 .clearfix { zoom: 1; }
```

This is a valid way ( as facebook do) and as [described here](http://robertnyman.com/2007/04/12/how-to-clear-css-floats-without-extra-markup-different-techniques-explained/)

However it works in FireFox : (look at the above picture)

But in chrome (v 24) it doesn't .

[image]

What am I missing ?

Comment: Looks like a chrome bug. `.clearfix:after { display:block }` with some content should do the same thing as having a real div at the end of the inside of the `.clearfix` span. But it doesn't.

Comment: @downoter , explanations are helpful !

Comment: I just had a look at facebook's code. They only seem to use this class on block-level content. Your first span is inline content AFAICT.

Comment: @wds yeah but then again , why to put clear on a div block which is automatically go to a new line.

Comment: @RoyiNamir I believe in most designs it's to stop different blocks from bleeding into each other.

Comment: @wds what do you mean by bldding ? `display:block` are seperated automatically. can you please elaborate ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir when the enclosing container doesn't take the height of its children, visually the contents of that container look like they're bleeding into the one below. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-actually-is-clearfix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jsbin example has TWO typos/syntax errors and the clearfix code is NOT correct.

1. `<span class=" clearfix">` you have a space before clearfix
2. `<span class='fll'>bbbbb </span>` you have single quotes instead of double quotes.

Change your html to:

```
      <div class="clearfix">aaa </div>
      <div class="fll">bbbbb </div>
```

and your CSS to:

```
.clearfix:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
    }
.clearfix { display: inline-table; }
* html .clearfix { height: 1%; }
.clearfix { display: block; }
```

and it works (all browsers,IE6-7 included) http://jsbin.com/ukaxav/19/

Comment: still u have single quote on second span

Comment: what do you mean "not working" ? it's the desired result. aaa shows first, in a new line bbbbb

Comment: +1. this is now working. for your information there is nothing wrong with space a the class and it can also be used as `'`. the problem was with the actual class rules.(are facebook doing it not the right way ? )

Comment: Royi, I guess HTML is forgiving but If I were you I wouldn't try to discover how different browsers interpret random spaces or single quotes in the HMTL... It might be that you get weird results especially on less modern ones.

Comment: With regards to the clearfix method I use since many years this one http://perishablepress.com/new-clearfix-hack/ which is rock-solid. (we have to support IE7 where I work..)

Comment: I agree. p.s. are u telling me that FB are doing it wrong ?  ( cause it is copy paste from their code)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24383/discussion-between-george-katsanos-and-royi-namir)

Comment: I asked you to confirm your question solved or not. If it's solved, then I just stop trying. Thanks

Comment: @BoltClock well , I didn't know it.

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos I've just seen your code lin e by line but you put on the clearfix  - display:block. that's not what I wanted to achieve. id it's display block it can work without all these extra styles.

Comment: Space within the `class` attribute value has nothing to do with the problem. The `class` is a space separated list of classes and if you have extra spaces at the start or at the end just adds more separators in the list and does't affect the behavior. The same applies to single quote vs quotation mark, either is allowed in HTML, you just have to use symmetric symbol (that is, start and end attribute value with the same character).

Answer (score 0):

```
.clearfix { display: block; }
```

Isn't it a "bit" more clean?

Comment: there is a difference between display block and clear both. my question is about clearing the floats.

Comment: Provide an exaustive jsfiddle and we'll can work on it. In your fiddle a simple "display: block" is enough.

Comment: here. http://robertnyman.com/2007/04/12/how-to-clear-css-floats-without-extra-markup-different-techniques-explained/ have a look at this where the section is _Generating Content Through CSS_

Comment: I did some test, seems Chrome add the same display propriety of the element that generated it. With an !important the problem isn't fixed. But if you set "display: block" to your span also the CSS generated element will have block state.  (not a solution, but it's what I've discovered)

Answer (score 0):

add **display:inline-block;** property to the parent div.

Code:

```
<div style="height: 100%; border: 1px solid blue;display: inline-block;"> 
<span class=" clearfix" style="">aaa </span>
<span class="fll">bbbbb </span>
</div>
```

Comment: this is causing the wrapper div to behave not as expected. div should be 100% by default.

Comment: You need to add width:100%; to the parent div.

Comment: Div being block element take 100% width by default of their parent container,  But in your case there is parent element to main div, so I have specified div width as 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Clearfix is intended to clear floats. meaning, on an element that **contains** float.
Not for clearing previous floats.So in your question, you are not putting the clearfix on the correct place, or misunderstand the principle.

Comment: I am clearing floats. this is what the after psuedo class is doing. look again at the code.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `width: 100%;` in your `fll`

so,

```
.clearfix:before {
    content: "";
    display: table; }

.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden; }

.clearfix { zoom: 1; }

 .fll
{
    float:left;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: addint 100% is another solution.  but then you can remove the clearfix. my question is why the clear fix doesnt work.

Comment: in here http://robertnyman.com/2007/04/12/how-to-clear-css-floats-without-extra-markup-different-techniques-explained/ you can see it is another solution but I want to use the clearfix.